# Как написать условие в цикле, чтобы обойти строки в которых отсутсвует нужное значение словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, словари

Есть двумерный список:

```
user_lists = [[{'first_name': 'Lena',
   'id': 476,
   'last_name': 'Samuylova',
   'bdate': '25.3.1988',
   'city': {'id': 1, 'title': 'Moscow'}},
  {'first_name': 'Darya',
   'id': 485,
   'last_name': 'Pavlova',
   'deactivated': 'banned'},
  {'first_name': 'Anatoly', 'id': 510, 'last_name': 'Karpenko'},
  {'first_name': 'Alexey',
   'id': 619,
   'last_name': 'Bardash',
   'deactivated': 'banned'}]]
```

нужно в этих списках и словарях посчитать количество городов, в которых живут пользователи. Данные нужно добавить в словарь - city_count = {}. Для этого делаю так:

```
for list_ in user_lists:
    for row in list_:
        city = row['city']['title']
        city_count[city] = city_count.get(city, 0) + 1
```

Но получаю ошибку:

Traceback (most recent call last): line 40, in city = row['city']['title'] KeyError: 'city'

Вероятно, потому что в некоторых строках отсутствует ['city'].

Как можно обойти данные случаи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто однострочник для подсчёта кол-ва разных городов:

```
print(len({data['city']['title'] for list_ in user_list for data in list_ if 'city' in data}))
```

А если нужен счётчик сколько раз какой город встречается, то так:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(data['city']['title'] for list_ in user_list for data in list_ if 'city' in data)
print(c)
```

В принципе, поскольку промежуточная переменная `list_` нам фактически не нужна, можно чуть сократить обе эти записи и вместо двойного цикла:

```
for list_ in user_list for data in list_
```

написать один, сокращённый с помощью приёма `распрямления` списка с помощью `sum`:

```
for data in sum(user_list, [])
```

Comment: ```for data in sum(user_list, [])``` работает ведь только для списка списков? список списков списков не развернет...

Answer (score 0):

определитесь уже с данными - они у вас ужасно оформлены

```
arr = [[{'first_name': 'Lena',
   'id': 476,
   'last_name': 'Samuylova',
   'bdate': '25.3.1988',
   'city': {'id': 1, 'title': 'Moscow'}},
  {'first_name': 'Darya',
   'id': 485,
   'last_name': 'Pavlova',
   'deactivated': 'banned'},
  {'first_name': 'Anatoly', 'id': 510, 'last_name': 'Karpenko'},
  {'first_name': 'Alexey',
   'id': 619,
   'last_name': 'Bardash',
   'deactivated': 'banned'}]]

cities = set()

for data in arr:
    for record in data:
        if 'city' in record:
            cities.add(record['city']['id'])

print(len(cities))
```

> нужно в этом списке посчитать количество городов, в которых живут
> пользователи

а то что у вас город только для одного пользователя указан - не смущает вообще?

и еще непонятно зачем список списков `[[]]` в котором только 1 список

Comment: Что значит "ужасно оформлены"? Список не один, в качестве примера привел только небольшой кусок. Суть в том, что именно из-за отсутствующих значений ['city'] в строках возникает ошибка. Хотел бы понять каким условием можно пропускать такие строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    city = row['city']['title']
except KeyError:
    continue
else:
    try:
        city_count[city] += 1
    except KeyError:
        city_count[city] = 1
```